# "Object of type PictureBook and identity yyy was not detached correctly" on live appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have an object PictureBook that contains a List< Picture> that's anotated with persistent.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,
    detachable = "true")
public class PictureBook {


/**
 * primary key - type encoded String
 */
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
private String key;

@Persistent
private String name;

@Persistent
private String creator;

@Persistent
private String link;

@Persistent
private String cover;

@Persistent(mappedBy = "pictureBook")
private List<Picture> pictures;
```

The picture class has a reference to the pictureBook class

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,
    detachable = "true")
public class Picture implements Serializable {


/**
 * primary key - type encoded String
 */
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
private String key;

@Persistent
private String albumName;

@Persistent
private String creator;

@Persistent
private String link;

@Persistent
private PictureBook pictureBook;

public Picture() {
}

public Picture(String albumName, String creator, String link) {
    this.albumName = albumName;
    this.creator = creator;
    this.link = link;
}
```

When testing locally everything goes as expected, but when I deploy to appengine I get an exception telling "Object of type xxx  and identity yyy was not detached correctly".
I get this when I query for all my PictureBook entities.
Can anyone help me out I'm really stuck on this one :/
The method with the query is following:

```
    public List<PictureBook> getAllPictureBooks() {
    log.info("retrieving all PictureBooks from datastore...");
    PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PMF.getInstance().getPersistenceManager();
    Query retrieveAllPictureBooks = persistenceManager.newQuery(PictureBook.class);
    List<PictureBook> albumList = null;
    List<PictureBook> albums = null;
    try {
        albumList = (List<PictureBook>) retrieveAllPictureBooks.execute();
                    for(PictureBook pictureBook: albumList){
                            System.out.println(pictureBook.getPictures().size());
                    }
        albums = (List<PictureBook>)persistenceManager.detachCopyAll(albumList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("an exception occured: \n" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (persistenceManager != null) {
            persistenceManager.close();
            log.info("persistenceManager closed");
        }
    }
    return albums;
}
```

Comment: you say you get this when you query, but then you don't post the code to do the query+detach. You also don't post what the log say when you do that query+detach. That should be the first place you look when debugging your problem. The majority of fields are default persistent so really don't see the point of most of those @Persistent

Comment: I added the code with the query and detachment, The @Persistent annotations are for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the pictures in the picturebook entity to the default fetch group fixed it